# Batch creation of a list of folders : can't echo accented characters

Tags: batch-file, non-ascii-characters

I use this batch instruction to generate a list of every subdirectory NOT containing a .zip file :

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%f in (*) do (
if not exist %%f\*.zip (
echo %%f >>G:\backup\folders.txt
)
)
```

The problem is this generates a list in which accents break the returned results, for instance

```
G:\backup\! d‚j… upload‚\
```

instead of

```
G:\backup\! déjà uploadé‚\
```

I read that batch can only deal with Unicode characters by default. There are tricks to make it eat paths with an accent, but I found NO trick to make it output (echo) results with accents.

Would you know how to do that ? I'd be most grateful!

Comment: How do you read list? `type G:\backup\folders.txt` should look fine.

Comment: I don't understand your question, LS_dev. I'm reading that list with notepad++, but any other program to read it gives the same result.

Comment: No, it won't. Even notepad++ supports [encoding](http://npp-wiki.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Encodings_And_Character_Display) choosing.

Answer (score 1):

The standard code page is [code page 850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) in non Unicode console windows in Western European countries on Windows which belongs to group of OEM code pages.

The standard code page is [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) in non Unicode GUI windows in Western European countries on Windows which belongs to group of ANSI code pages although this code page is not an [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI) standard. But Windows-1252 is similar to standardized code page [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) with the exception of the characters with code value 128 (0x80) to 159 (0x9F).

As most folder and file names are created in Windows GUI applications, characters with a code value greater 127 are often using Windows-1252.

For example the folder name **! déjà uploadé‚** is in bytes (hexadecimal)

```
21 20 64 E9 6A E0 20 75 70 6C 6F 61 64 E9 82
```

Those 15 bytes are displayed with a font using code page 1252 as **! déjà uploadé‚** but with using code page 850 as **! d‚j… upload‚'**

The solution for this batch file is to use command **chcp** (change code page) before outputting the folder names with **echo** and redirecting them into a text file opened later in a Windows GUI editor.

```
@echo off
chcp 1252>nul
for /d /r %%f in (*) do (
    if not exist %%f\*.zip (
        echo %%f>>G:\backup\folders.txt
    )
)
```

Note: There is no space left to `>nul` and `>>G:\backup\folders.txt`. For an explanation see answer on [when running batch file from java , 1 randomly appears before >>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27215340/3074564).

Comment: It is correct that this is a codepage issue. The default console codepage on English Windows is 437. Use the `chcp` command without a parameter to see the current console codepage.