# when running batch file from java , 1 randomly appears before >>

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

i am trying to run a batch file from my java code

this is the batch file line :

```
C:\Users\abdelk\workspace\Symmetrix>symconfigure -sid 13 -cmd "create dev count=16, size=139840, emulation=FBA , config=TDEV;" commit -nop >> out_file.txt
```

when i run the batch file from my code, **"1"** randomly appears before the ">>". so line in cmd becomes like that :

```
C:\Users\abdelk\workspace\Symmetrix>symconfigure -sid 13 -cmd "create dev count=16, size=139840, emulation=FBA , config=TDEV;" commit -nop  **1>>** outfile.txt
```

I don't know how can i remove this random appearing "1"

this is how i run the batch file from my code

```
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start "+functions_object.edit_host_name(current_host_name)+"_Meta.bat",null,new  File("C:\\Users\\abdelk\\workspace\\Project"));
```

Comment: Probably stdout stream..Does this 1 cause any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take a look on Microsoft's TechNet article [using command redirection operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Numeric **1** is an equivalent for handle **stdout** (standard output).

In batch files numeric **1** is omitted on redirection **stdout**.

For example put those 2 lines into a batch file and run it

```
echo This is just a redirect test.>CapturedStandardOutput.txt
@pause
```

You will see that `cmd.exe` automatically inserts  `1` (space and 1) left to the redirection operator `>`.

In general it is not advisable to add already in batch file **1** for **stdout**.

Why?

Look what is executed with:

```
echo This is just a redirect test.1>CapturedStandardOutput.txt
@pause
```

You see in console window:

```
echo This is just a redirect test.1 1>CapturedStandardOutput.txt
```

And the file *CapturedStandardOutput.txt* contains the line:

```
This is just a redirect test.1
```

The solution is to use in batch file:

```
echo This is just a redirect test. 1>CapturedStandardOutput.txt
```

This results in execution of the line:

```
echo This is just a redirect test.  1>CapturedStandardOutput.txt
```

And there is now the line below in file *CapturedStandardOutput.txt*:

```
This is just a redirect test.
```

What you can't see here in the browser window is that the line in the text file ends now with a trailing space in comparison to first example. Therefore best is to use `>` and `>>` always without **1** as otherwise it is not really simple to control what is written to the text file.

One more hint:

To redirect a text to a file which ends with 1, 2, ..., 9 it is necessary to escape the number with `^`.

Execution of a batch file with

```
echo Number is ^1>CapturedStandardOutput.txt
@pause
```

results in executing the command line

```
echo Number is 1 1>CapturedStandardOutput.txt
```

and in file *CapturedStandardOutput.txt* the line

```
Number is 1
```

with no trailing space at end of the line.

**0** left to `>` and `>>` must not be escaped to get number **0** written into a text file.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it made things very clear now