# Executing a java jar file in a bat file for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to run a java jar file in a bat file in a for loop based on input from a file, each line in the file contains an argument:

```
SET jar-path="C:\\tools\\myJar.jar"
SET out-path=C:\tmp\out
SET args-file=C:\data\args.txt

for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("%args-file%") do (
    java -jar %jar-path% %%a %out-path%
    :: start /wait java -jar %jar-path% %%a %out-path%
)
```

Where args.txt contains:

```
a
b
c
```

But the loop just iterates 3 times without running the jar file. If I do it outside the loop it works, any suggestions?

Comment: Is this the whole content of your bat file or just a snippet?

Comment: Yes its the whole content

Comment: Is it possible that the jar is being executed but does nothing?

Comment: No each execution takes 10-15 seconds and when I run the above bat file it just terminates after 1 second, it does 3 iterations though

Comment: And what if you use the `start /wait java -jar %jar-path% %%a %out-path%` line instead? Still terminating after 1 second?

Comment: Yes gives the same result

Comment: It might be interesting what's the errorlevel after each iteraton of the loop. Add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` as first line of your script and `echo !errorlevel!` below `java -jar %jar-path% %%a %out-path%`

Answer (score 0):

What about using following batch code:

```
set "jar-path=C:\tools\myJar.jar"
set "out-path=C:\tmp\out"
set "args-file=C:\data\args.txt"

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%args-file%") do (
    "java.exe" -jar "%jar-path%" %%a "%out-path%"
)
```

It makes a huge difference where the double quotes are used on assigning a string to an environment variable, see for example [Assign string values with space to environment variables right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28649897/3074564) for an explanation.

It would be also best to specify `java.exe` with full path if that is possible because batch file is used always on same computer. In batch files it should be avoided that command line interpreter has to use the environment variables **PATHEXT** and **PATH** to find out which application to run.